# Do I need a sim card to start a Windows Phone for the first time?

Tags: sim

So I just bought a 930. My current sim is broken and I will not receive a new one until tomorrow. Can I start my phone anyway? Like being able to download apps and such.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes of course you can. These days all phones are required to do so by law so in case of any emergency you can use the emergency number to call the police or fire department.
You can use your windows phone normally but you can't use cellular features like calling or using the internet, however you can connect to the wifi and download apps or browse the net etc!

Comment: Correct. Just started my new 930 without a sim and it worked.

Comment: The only problem I think is that you can't start the backup recovery with no 3G. I don't know if it already work with just wifi.